# Sparse to Dense Matrix reduces its dimension when there are repetitions

Tags: matrix, julia, sparse-matrix

I have a set of indices that I want to convert them to encodings. In order to do so :

```
i = [2, 1, 3, 4]
s = sparse(i, 1:lenght(i), 1)
s = full(s);
```

This works fine as expected but when the array `i = [2, 1, 3, 3]`. The `full` function gives a 3 by 4 matrix instead of 4 by 4. Julia thinks that the last row is unnecessary and deletes it which ,for my case, is not.

Is it possible to create a square matrix by using `sparse` and `full` when there are repetitions inside the index `array i`?

B.R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just supply the dimensions you want as additional arguments, e.g.:

```
s = sparse(i, 1:length(i), 1, 4, 4)
```

The details are explained in help for `sparse`.